# Wind turbine in water

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

I have a 3D printed wind turbine (I got the design from a research paper). If I conduct a particle image velocimetry experiment in a water flume instead of a wind tunnel, what should I expect as the water is 1000 times denser than air? Also, based on the velocity deficit profile, how can I measure the power output of the wind turbine?

Comment: You need to get data at the same Reynold's number as the wind turbine operating in air.  For an example of this, see https://news.arizona.edu/story/new-vertical-water-tunnel-helps-engineers-understand-aerodynamics-delta-wings

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helped me

Comment: Arif, I'm glad I could help.  Good luck with your application.